# Migrated wordpress multisite to ubuntu with nginx - resources not found

Tags: nginx, wordpress, wordpress-mu

I recently moved my wordpress multisite install from shared hosting to a could ssd server running ubuntu, I also changed it to run with nginx.

Everything is working fine, except that a handful of resources don't seem to be loading. I have a checkout within a plugin from wpmu-dev (The plugin is called pro-sites and allows users to pay to sign up for a blog). When I go to my checkout page, all the resources from just this plugin are returning a 404 error - however, when I follow the path of the files that return the error I can find them in my SFTP client, they are where they are supposed to be. What's strange, is on my page I have other resources from the same plugins directory that are loading fine.

It's probably worth mentioning that when I migrated my site I changed my url from www.example.com to just example.com - I can't see how that would affect this though. I also have an SSL certificate and https is forced on the checkout page.

Here is my nginx conf file:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen 443 ssl;
server_name skizzar.com *.skizzar.com;

ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/skizzar/www.skizzar.com.chained.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/skizzar/www.skizzar.com.key;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:!aNULL;

root /usr/share/nginx/skizzar;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args ;
    rewrite files/(.+) /wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 last;
}

location /nothingtosee {
    auth_basic "Admin Login";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/pma_pass;
}

location ~ /favicon.ico {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
access_log  /var/log/nginx/$host-access.log;
error_log   /var/log/nginx/wpms-error.log;
}
```

Here is my most recent errors - obviously they are refferrig to a file missing at /usr/share/nginx/skizzar/prosite - however, I'm not sure there has ever been a file here

```
2016/01/07 11:08:58 [error] 21614#0: *116 open() "/usr/share/nginx/skizzar/pro-site" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 81.158.229.186, server: skizzar.com, request: $
2016/01/07 11:09:07 [error] 21614#0: *116 "/usr/share/nginx/skizzar/pro-site/index.php" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 81.158.229.186, server: skizzar.com, $
2016/01/07 11:09:52 [error] 21614#0: *116 "/usr/share/nginx/skizzar/pro-site/index.php" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 81.158.229.186, server: skizzar.com, $
```

Any help or advice here would be very useful as i'm out of ideas

UPDATE: just realised that /pro-site is the checkout page, so it shouldn't be looking for a directory there

Comment: In your logs you can see IP address of client. Try to search, which URL this client tried immediately before attempting this URL and I think, you will find a root of problem.

Comment: @JanMarek actually now I think about it /pro-site is the checkout page...hadn't clocked that before as i just changed it...not sure if that makes any difference here?

Comment: Can you please post the URL(s) you're requesting with your web browser and applicable access logs.

Comment: There are more characters after the `$` in the error log. Is there anything useful there?

Comment: @SamSkirrow If it is a checkout page, you must have this URL somewhere in code of this site. Check it. I have no other ideas... You will need to place to this directory some code to handle this URL...